# Who's a person with two independant zikas supposed to marry?

Tags: halacha, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Woman A was married to B, and B died without children. A should do Yibum with C but never got around to it. Instead she married D.

D then died without children, but has a brother E.

Who should A marry, C or E?

(According to Sefardim who do Yibum) Who does Yibbum C or E or Should they both do Chalitza?

Comment: Was she even allowed to marry D before doing chalitza with C?

Comment: @Cnsersmoit no, but she did it anyways

Comment: @Cnsersmoit The better question is if she is allowed to do Yibbum altogether as she's a katlanis, but perhaps she married F somewhere in the middle to a void that issue

Comment: I thought she isn't a katlanis until 3 die, but i may be wrong.

Comment: If Yevama l'shuk is an issur kares (like one opinion in the gemara) then this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

שומרת יבם שנבעלה בזנות לא נאסרה ליבם אם הוא ישראל שוע אהע קנט ג

A woman who was waiting for yibum and was together with a different man is not forbidden to the original brother if he is not a kohen. Shulchan aruch even haezer 159 3.

So she should marry c. If he does chalitza she can marry e.

Comment: But that's talking about zenus, but the question is if she married d. Unless maybe the marriage wouldn't be counted because she first needs to do yibum/chalitza

Comment: @user613 It seems that she couldn't have been halachically married to D, so this would apply. See comments on the question.